# Validar tamaño de un archivo - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy cargando archivos desde el form al servidor de la siguiente manera:

```
$files = Input::file('archivoExamenMedicoDetalle');
for($i = 0; $i < $contadorDetalle; $i++)
{
   $file = $files[$i] ;
   $rutaImagen = '';
   $destinationPath = '/carpetacontenedora/';
   if(isset($file))
   {
       $filename = $destinationPath . file->getClientOriginalName();
       \Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, \File::get($file));
       $rutaImagen = 'carpetacontenedora/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();


       $data['fotoExamenMedicoDetalle'] =  $rutaImagen;

   }
   else
   {
       $rutaImagen = $request['fotoExamenMedicoDetalle'][$i];
   }
}
```

Según lo que estuve consultando, validar el tamaño de un archivo desde java script no es posible, sólo se puede hacer directamente desde el servidor, así que supuse que hacer lo siguiente podría validar que si el archivo supera el límite permitido no dejara continuar y se quedara en el formulario.

```
if(isset($file))
   {
       $filename = $destinationPath . file->getClientOriginalName();

       $tamañoArchivoByte = filesize($file);

       $tamañoArchivoKbyte = $tamañoArchivoByte/1024;

       if($tamañoArchivoKbyte > 2)           
       {
         return ('Supera el tamaño máximo permitido.');
       }
       else
       {
          \Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, \File::get($file));
          $rutaImagen = 'carpetacontenedora/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
          $data['fotoExamenMedicoDetalle'] =  $rutaImagen;
       }

   }
```

El problema es que siempre se está yendo por el else aun cuando el tamaño del archivo supera el supuesto permitido. No sé si lo estoy validando de la manera correcta (teniendo en cuenta que estoy en el store del controlador) o se puede hacer en el request de laravel.

Comment: de que tamaño en bytes debe ser tu validación?, ¿has usado Validator?

Comment: De 2560 bytes. No, no lo he usado, hasta ahora lo estoy intentando hacer de una manera "tradicional"

Comment: file('file')->getClientSize(); ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez una consulta, la respuesta en que unidad de medida lo retorna???

Comment: @AbrahamRosales el tamaño va en bytes, pero me parece que siendo lo que reporta el cliente no debería ser tomado como valor seguro. para limitar tamaños lo mejor es `upload_max_filesize ` y `post_max_size` en el php.ini para mod_apache, `FcgidMaxRequestLen` para fastcgi, `client_max_body_size ` para nginx

Comment: @aloMalbarez totalmente de acuerdo, muy amable!

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas de validación que puede usar es `Validator`

debes de importar `use Validator;`

```
$validacion = Validator::make($inputs->all(), [
        'archivoExamenMedicoDetalle'=> 'max:2560',//indicamos el valor maximo
]);

if ($validacion->fails()) {
   return ('Supera el tamaño máximo permitido.'); 
} else {
  //aquí en el caso de que este todo bien
}
```

Comment: Esto puede ir directamente en el controlador?

Comment: si claro es en tu controllador